Maximum of $P=\dfrac{1}{a+b}+\dfrac{1}{b+c}+\dfrac{1}{c+a}.$

Let $a,b,c\geq 1$ such that $a+b+c=9$. Find $\max$ and $\min$ of
$P=\dfrac{1}{a+b}+\dfrac{1}{b+c}+\dfrac{1}{c+a}.$

My attempt
By C-S, I have $P\geq\dfrac{9}{2(a+b+c)}=\dfrac{9}{2.9}=\dfrac{1}{2}$. This holds when $a=b=c=3$.
I'm stuck at finding its maximum. I guess $\max P=\dfrac{3}{4}$ and this holds when $(a,b,c)=(1,1,7)$ and its permutation. I'm looking for any path as "elemantary" as possible (using well-know inequalities or simple evaluations). Any help I'm very grateful.

You can use calculus, for instance.

There is a maximum. You all are missing the condition $ a,b,c \ge 1 $

A convex function defined on a convex set attains its maximum at an extremal point of the set ...

Let's set $c = 9 - (a + b)$. Then the $P$ becomes:
$$
P = \frac{1}{a + b} + \frac{1}{9 -a} + \frac{1}{9 - b}
$$
and we have restriction:
$$
c \geqslant 1 \iff 9 - (a + b) \geqslant 1 \iff 8 \geqslant a + b
$$
Constraints $a,b \geqslant 1$ and $8 \geqslant a + b$ give us following region to work with (for coordinates $a$ and $b$):

I will show, that the maximal value cannot appear inside of that region (that is not on the border).
Let's fix $b$. Then $P$ become single-variable function of $a$ on interval $[1, 8-b]$ and we have:
$$
P = \frac{1}{a + b} + \frac{1}{9 -a} + \frac{1}{9 - b} = \boxed{\frac{9 + b}{(a + b)(9-a)}} + \frac{1}{9 - b}
$$
Since $\frac{1}{9 - b}$ is constant, thus we can focus on highlighted expression. The numerator of that fraction is again constant and denominator is a quadtratic function of variable $a$. Expression $(a + b)(9- a)$ has a global maximum at the point $a = \frac{9 - b}{2}$. This point is indeed inside our domain, because:
$$
1 \leqslant \frac{9 - b}{2} \leqslant 8 - b \iff b \leqslant 7
$$
which holds true in our problem.
Therefore $P$ achieves global minimum at the point $a = \frac{9 - b}{2}$ in the interval $[1, 8 - b]$ and thus its maximal value can appear only in points $a = 1$ or $a = 8 - b$.
Now if $a = 1$ or $a = 8 - b$, then:
$$
P = \frac{1}{b + 1} + \frac{1}{9 - b} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{10}{(b + 1)(9 - b)} + \frac{1}{8}
$$
By very similar argument as before you can show, that this function achieves is maximal value only in those edge cases, that is when $b = 1$ or $b = 7$.
In the end the maximal value is:
$$
\frac{10}{(1 + 1)(9 - 1)} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{3}{4} 
$$

Suppose we have a triple $(a,b,c)$ where $c$ i is largest and write $P(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{x+y} + \frac{1}{y+z} + \frac{1}{z+x}$.  If $a > 1$, then for small $t$ (take $t=a-1$ really) consider $\bar{a} := a - t$ and $\bar{c}:=c+t$. I claim $P(\bar a, b, \bar c) > P(a,b,c)$.
Indeed $P(\bar a,b, \bar c) - P(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{\bar{a} + b} - \frac{1}{a + b} + \frac{1}{\bar{c} + b} - \frac{1}{c+b}$ since $\bar a + \bar c = a+c$, and
this is $\frac{(a+b) - (\bar{a}+b)}{(a+b)(\bar{a}+b)}+ \frac{(c+b)-(\bar{c}+b)}{(c+b)(\bar{c}+b)} = t \Big(\frac{1}{(a+b)(\bar{a}+b)} -\frac{1}{(c+b)(\bar c+b) }\Big)>0$ as the second denominator is bigger (as $\bar{a} < a \le c < \bar{c})$
Hence $P(a,b,c) \le P(1,b,c+a-1)$. Of course, the same argument applies to $b$ instead of $a$, so $P(a,b,c) \le P(1,1,7) = 3/4$. The argument also shows that $(1,1,7)$ and its permutations are the only maxima.
